# Position elements of same class, and variable top with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the top position of ".bottom-container" elements be equal to ".top-content" top position, plus ".top" height. The issue is that top and hight values change every time, the div ".container" that contains these elements repeats with the same classes, I had a good answer before to solve the element .each() for height but need to add the top.

I put a class of "level-1", "level-2", etc, to change top position of red box container.

How can I do: .bottom-container top (green box) = .top-content top (red box container with level class) + .top height (red box).

This is the code example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topContainer = $(".container .top-content .top");
  var botContainer = $(".container .column .bottom-container");
  tl = topContainer.length;
  bl = botContainer.length;

  topContainer.each(function(topIndex) {
    var _self = $(this);
    var topHeight = _self.height();


    botContainer.each(function(botIndex) {

      if (botIndex >= (bl) * (topIndex / (tl)) && botIndex < (bl) * (topIndex + 1 / (tl))) {

        var bc = $(this);
        bc.css({
          "top": topHeight + "px",
        });
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.top-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.level-1 {
  top: 10px;
}

.level-2 {
  top: 20px;
}

.level-3 {
  top: 30px;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.bottom-container {
 position : relative;
 background-color: green;
}

.bottom-content {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="top-content level-1">
    <div>other thing</div>
    <div class="top">
      Height change with dynamically content.
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 1
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 3
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="top-content level-2">
    <div>other thing</div>
    <div class="top">
      Height change with dynamically content, is always different size.
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 1
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>


<div class="container">

  <div class="top-content level-3">
    <div>other thing</div>
    <div class="top">
      Height change with dynamically content, is always different size.is always different size.is always different size.
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 1
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: do you have to do this with jQuery?  You could achieve what you're looking to accomplish with CSS's flexbox?

Comment: I review CSS's flexbox, but I don't see how to do that with it. This is data loading inside a php loop from a database, so I think JQuery can works fine.

Comment: i ask because basing a layout on absolute positioning of DOM elements can get broken really quickly (hence you've asked this question once before, but are now asking it again because you have another layout issue you need to resolve).

it just seems to me that your question is about how to create a consistent layout, where flexbox (or maybe even a table if this is tabular data?) could help. Where the data is coming from is irrelevant as it's not a data issue, it's a presentation issue of the data.

Comment: Ok, yes I need something consistent to accomplish the layout. It has many changes of styles according to the data input, to achieve a final graphic flow. Maybe I have to review all the layout to see if flexbox or tables can works better. The biggest part of the layout is done, just left to do a top part that is going to be above to 2, 3, 4... columns, with different top position and height. So, the data is not going to display, also to affect the layout conditionally.